# Creating scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, graph

Can someone help me with how to create a scatterplot. I have written the following code, however, it is not the scatter plot [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZD2N9.png) that I expected as all data only concentrate 3 values of x-variable

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from scipy.stats import skew

from warnings import filterwarnings
filterwarnings('ignore')

df_transactions = pd.read_csv('transactions.csv')
daily_revenue= df_transactions.groupby("days_after_open").sum()['revenue']
df_transactions["daily_revenue"] = daily_revenue  

x = df_transactions["days_after_open"]
y = df_transactions["daily_revenue"]

plt.scatter(x,y,alpha=0.2)    
plt.xlabel("Days After Open (days)")
plt.ylabel("Daily Reveue ($)")
    
plt.savefig("plot")
```

[dataframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAOKd.png)

Comment: Hi Amali! And welcome to SO. Make sure to provide some data (a few row of your dataframe) so we may help you.

Comment: Hi Serge,
I just add the snippet of my dataframe and what my scatterplot looks like

Answer (score 0):

Please define the 'daily_revenue' following before moving to the scatter plot.

```
 y = df_transactions["daily_revenue"]
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but let me rephrase my question again,
How I can create scatterplot from the group by function that I just created?